# Create a Rock-Paper-Scissors game using a class for each

Tags: c#, oop

Tough assignment today. I've been working in circles for about five hours.  I just can't wrap my head around this and see through the fog on this one.  Here is the assignment our teacher assigned tonight:

> Create a new Visual Studio Console Application named
>   RockPaperScissors.
>
> The game Rock/Paper/Scissors has the following rules:
>
> - Scissor always wins against Paper
> - Rock always wins against Scissors
> - Paper always wins against Rock
>
> Create the following three classes that
>   follow these rules:
>
> - PlayerRock – Always performs the Act() of Rock.
> - PlayerScissors –
>     Always performs the Act() of Scissors.
> - PlayerPaper – Always performs
>     the Act() of Paper.
>
> Create a Game class that has a method named
>   Fight() that satisifies these requirements:
>
> - The Fight() method accepts two parameters:  Player1 and Player2.
> - The Fight() method calls both player's Act() methods.
> - The Fight() method returns the winning player using the Rock/Paper/Scissors rules above.
>
> After 100 rounds, which player wins?

I can easily do the game logic and script this game out, no problem.  How to make it fire the Act methods for each weapon? And pass a player1 and player2 as well?  Do I need classes to create new player objects?  I've got classes for Rock, Paper, Scissors, but they basically only have a method inside them returning rock, paper and scissors.  I'm not asking for anyone to make this game for me, but can anybody get me pointed in the right direction? Thanks all!

Comment: Have you tested some code yet? If you have, would you please share it with us? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you need an `abstract` base class called `Player` with an abstract `Act()` method that returns an `GameAction` (could be simply an `enum`, unless you want to encode the game logic in the `GameAction` class, which is fine).

You could derive the three classes `PlayerRock` etc., from `Player`, and override the `Act()` method in each derived class.

Call `Game.Fight(Player player1, Player player2)`, passing in two instances of your derived player classes. Inside `Fight(...)` you should call the `Act()` method on both players, and decide who wins (if anyone) based on the result.

The same player will win each time though, don't need 100 rounds to show that. Perhaps you are supposed to generate some players at random, or have some players with more subtle strategies later on?

Example of the abstract and concrete classes:

```
namespace RockPaperScissors
{
    enum GameAction
    {
        Rock,
        Paper,
        Scissors
    }

    abstract class Player
    {
        public abstract GameAction Act();
    }

    class PlayerRock : Player
    {
        public override GameAction Act()
        {
            return GameAction.Rock;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I mark the method as abstract as well as the class, it isn't going to allow me to return anything though, right?

Comment: You can declare the abstract method with `abstract public Action Act();`. This is basically saying *"any non-abstract class that derives from `Player` must implement an `Act()` method that returns an `Action`".*

Comment: Avoid using the name `Action`. There already is a type of that name in the system namespace.

Comment: I think that's what he's using.  I can't get it implemented in my derived classes though.

Comment: @EricLippert true, to avoid hiding `System.Action` another name would be better. I thought that not worrying about name conflicts was the whole point of namespaces though ;)

Comment: @ScottVMeyers to implement `GameAction Act()` in your derived classes you have to explicitly `override` that method - if you are using a recent Visual Studio it helpfully suggests things like that if you forget.

Comment: Okay, cool, I get that, I can override the method.  But what should I have it return?

Comment: `PlayerRock`'s `Act()` method will return `GameAction.Rock`, etc.

Comment: That's what I tried, but it doesn't like it.  I don't have GameAction existing anywhere currently.   Have you gone away from the type being Action?  I can't rename that GameAction.

Comment: Yes I renamed the `enum` from `Action` to `GameAction` - that's a trivial change, you may be able to do it with a *right click->Rename* in Visual Studio.

Comment: Ohh my gosh, I completely forgot about your Enum!  Okay, last question, then I'll get this all done and stop buggin you for today.  Where does the Enum live?  In the main method?  In the base class?

Comment: It has to go somewhere where all the classes that use it can see it. Logically makes sense to go at the top of the namespace to me, but could be in lots of places - see the code I added.

Comment: Perfect.  Hey, thank you so much for the time!!  You really helped me out.

Comment: No problem, hope the assignment goes well :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a 5 minutes version of the above. (For reference).

```
namespace RockPaperScissors
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var player1 = new PlayerPaper()
            {
                Name = "Derek",

            };

            var player2 = new PlayerScissors()
            {
                Name = "Jonny"
            };

            var winner = new Battle(player1, player2).PlayMatchUp();

            if (winner == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Game was a draw.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The Winner of this battle : {0}", winner.Name);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }

    public abstract class Player
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public abstract GameAction Act();
    }

    public class PlayerRock : Player
    {
        public override GameAction Act()
        {
            return GameAction.Rock;
        }
    }

    public class PlayerPaper : Player
    {
        public override GameAction Act()
        {
            return GameAction.Paper;
        }
    }

    public class PlayerScissors : Player
    {
        public override GameAction Act()
        {
            return GameAction.Scissors;
        }
    }

    public enum GameAction
    {
        Rock,
        Paper,
        Scissors
    }

    public class Battle
    {
        private readonly Player _player1;
        private readonly Player _player2;

        public Battle(Player player1, Player player2)
        {
            this._player1 = player1;
            this._player2 = player2;
        }

        public  Player PlayMatchUp()
        {

            var result = WinningHand(_player1.Act(), _player2.Act());

            if (_player1.Act() == result)
            {
                return _player1;
            }

            if (_player2.Act() == result)
            {
                return _player2;
            }

            return null;
        }
        private  GameAction? WinningHand(GameAction p1, GameAction p2)
        {
            if (p1 == GameAction.Paper && p2 == GameAction.Rock)
            {
                return GameAction.Paper;
            }

            if (p1 == GameAction.Paper && p2 == GameAction.Scissors)
            {
                return GameAction.Scissors;
            }

            if (p1 == GameAction.Scissors && p2 == GameAction.Paper)
            {
                return GameAction.Scissors;
            }

            if (p1 == GameAction.Scissors && p2 == GameAction.Rock)
            {
                return GameAction.Rock;
            }

            if (p1 == GameAction.Rock && p2 == GameAction.Paper)
            {
                return GameAction.Paper;
            }

            if (p1 == GameAction.Rock && p2 == GameAction.Scissors)
            {
                return GameAction.Rock;
            }

            return null;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The assignment specified that *"The Fight() method accepts two parameters: Player1 and Player2."*.  Your `PlayMatchUp()` and `WinningHand()` methods seems a bit clunky to me, take a look at `Outcome()` in the other suggested solution to see how simply this can be done. The rest looks good though.

Answer (score 0):

Go by *incremental steps*. First, you don't need separated classes for `Rock`, `Paper` etc. `enum` is quite enough:

```
  public enum Action {
    Rock,
    Paper,
    Scissors
  }

  public static class ActionExtensions {
    // +1 left wins, 0 - draw, -1 right wins
    public static int Outcome(this Action left, Action right) {
      if (left == right)
        return 0;
      else if ((left == Action.Rock) && (right == Action.Scissors) ||
               (left == Action.Paper) && (right == Action.Rock) ||
               (left == Action.Scissors) && (right == Action.Paper))
        return 1;
      else
        return -1;
    }
  }
```

Then implement `Player` and its descendents

```
  public abstract class Player {
    public abstract Action Act();
  }

  public sealed class PlayerRock: Player {
    public override Action Act() {
      return Action.Rock;
    }

    public override String ToString() {
      return "I'm Rock player; I always say 'Rock'";
    }
  }
  ...
```

Finally `Game`:

```
  public static class Game {
    public static Player Fight(Player player1, Player player2) {
      if (null == player1)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("player1"); 
      else if (null == player2)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("player2"); 

      int score1 = 0;
      int score2 = 0;

      const int upToScore = 100;
      const int maxParties = 1000;

      for (int match = 0; match < maxParties; ++maxParties) {
        if (score1 >= upToScore)
          return player1;
        else if (score2 >= upToScore)
          return player2;

        int outcome = player1.Act().Outcome(player2.Act());

        if (outcome > 0)
          score1 += 1;
        else if (outcome < 0)
          score2 += 1;
      }

      // maxParties passed, and no-one has won; so no winner
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Do not forget to test

```
  var player1 = new PlayerRock();
  var player2 = new PlayerScissors(); 

  Console.Write(Game.Fight(player1, player2).ToString());
```

Comment: If you pass in two instances of the same player class, won't you get an infinite loop? Might be better to play 100 rounds as the assignment stated, rather than first to 100 wins.

Comment: Dmitry, that's beautiful, man.  I think most of it even makes sense to me, and I can change enough parts to make him think I might have come up with it.  But where do I put the enum?  Does it just go in the main method?

Comment: You should also be aware that instructors may check on this and similar sites for exactly this reason, I'd be careful about copying and pasting a full solution that you don' t fully understand.

Comment: I'm not going to use it, it's a great tool, but cried too much over the other version.  If I can't finish by the time class starts I'm going to copy his code, but I like the way your solution feels, I just can't put the pieces together. I can't get the abstract class to implement correctly

Comment: The abstract class is basically the whole point of this assignment, calling Act() on a Person (where you don't have to know the derived class). I'll add a bit of code to my solution.